# Expiring cache key path trees for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

If I’ve got a resource with routes like /whatevers/1 is there a way to expire action cache key paths for all /show pages under that resource?

I’m using memcached as my caching backend if that helps.

(Really hoping I don’t have to iterate through all keys myself…)

Comment: Looks like if I wasn’t using memcache, I could make a call to `expire_fragment` and supply a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do exactly this other than iterating through the keys and expiring them.

So don’t :)

Instead, incorporate version numbers into your cache key paths, increment them to bust the cache, and let memcache take care of itself as it inevitably reclaims old cache keyspace.